# Polearm Gamble questions for a Swordmage

Tags: dnd-4e

Okay, so suppose I have a Glaive. If I have Polearm Gamble, I can hit someone with an opportunity attack if they try to enter an adjacent space. And Heavy Blade Opportunity would let me hit with an at-will weapon power instead of a basic attack. So my questions are, supposing that an enemy from two spaces away enters into an adjacent space...

1. If my weapon power is Booming Blade, can it hit? I'm asking since Booming Blade is Melee 1. (And I think the hit technically happens while the enemy's two spaces away.)
2. If my weapon power is Luring Strike, if it hits, how does the enemy slide work if the enemy is two spaces away?

Comment: This seems like it would be better as two separate questions, since they cover largely different things. The second question would be the same even when simply using the power on your own turn rather than as an opportunity attack.

Comment: Also, I don't know if one of us is using an outdated source or something, but according to http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Booming_blade, Booming Blade is Melee Weapon, not Melee 1, which would kind of invalidate the premise of question 1.

Comment: My Character Builder says it's Melee 1, but yeah if it were Melee Weapon then the second thing would be resolved.

Comment: I'll have to wait until I get home to see what's up with that.

Comment: My Builder also says Melee 1, but that seems to be a mistake, since I can't find anything indicating it was ever actually Melee 1, before or after errata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Polearm Gamble's attack happens before the enemy moves adjacent to you.

From the PHB, p204 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Polearm Gamble**
>   When a nonadjacent enemy *enters a square adjacent to you*, you can make an *opportunity attack* against that enemy.

So Polearm Gamble's attack is an opportunity attack.

From the RC, p246:

> **Opportunity Attack**
>   Opportunity Action
>   Trigger: ...

Opportunity attacks use opportunity actions.

From the RC, p197 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Interrupt:** Just like an immediate interrupt, an opportunity action interrupts its trigger, *taking place before the trigger finishes*.

Opportunity actions take place before their trigger; therefore Polearm Gamble's attack takes place while the target is still 2 squares away.

#### Booming Blade can hit.

I'm not sure what kind of crack the Character Builder is smoking, but Booming Blade's range is Melee: Weapon per page 27 of the FRPG. Thus, as long as you're wielding a reach weapon (like a glaive), Booming Blade is a melee 2 attack.

Note, though, that Booming Blade requires the target to *start their next turn* adjacent to you to take the extra damage, so if you use it during their turn with Heavy Blade Opportunity then they won't be at risk until their *next* turn.

#### Luring Strike needs help to slide the enemy.

From the RC on forced movement, p212:

> **Distance, Specific Destination, or Both:** The power or other effect that produces forced movement specifies a distance in squares, a specified destination square, or both for the movement.
>   ...When a destination is specified, it is absolute; the creature or effect must either move the target to that destination or not move it at all. Often a destination is combined with a distance, which means the target can be moved to the destination only if it is no farther away than the specified distance.

Luring Strike specifies both a distance and a destination; if the distance isn't enough to reach the destination, then you don't slide the target. Since the target will be 2 squares away when you make an attack with Polearm Gamble, slide 1 won't be sufficient to get the target to the required destination. If you have something to increase your slide distance (such as the popular Rushing Cleats), however, then you'll have enough slide distance and will be able to move the target with Luring Strike.